# Subsurface scattering different in render than in viewport

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, artifacts, subsurface-scattering

When I'm in the viewport the materials on this model look nice without any substantial weird green artifacts but when I render it, the skin on my character becomes really green and gross looking.

[image]

[image]

I feel like this should be an easy fix that I just can't see but hope someone can help.

Here is the blender file:[image]

Comment: I can not solve your problem. But I just want to mention that I downloaded your file and it works perfect. I didn‘t change anything in your file and rendered it on my computer. The rendered picture and the picture in the viewport look exactely the same like your first one. Hope you can use this information somehow.

Comment: To me it looks like denoising artifacts. That in combination with Subsurface Subsurface Scattering can look ugly sometimes. You have different settings under Render Properties -> Sampling  -> Viewport/Denoise and Render/Denoise
Try matching them or turning off denoising for the final render.

Comment: @Alex I think you have a different GPU, so Blender picked another (or no) denoiser for you.
Complete information about denoising in a book called 'Cycles Encyclopedia' (paid)

Comment: I had that problem with my donut, I’m new lol. But I adjusted the lighting and that solved it.